# creating virtual directory of .htaccess files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've searched all forums recently including StackOverflow, but couldn't find any solution how to use .htaccess files. I've heard that virtual directories are created using this service.

I want the virtual path of user profile to be displayed like this if user name is set

www.example.com/username

or if username is not set, then user profiles will be displayed with this link

www.example.com/profile.php?id=134531

Just like facebook.

Can anyone post me an exact code of this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for "Mod rewrite" or "RewriteRule", that'll get you much better search results. There's millions of pages devoted to that.

Comment: None of them helped because I know absolutely nothing about .htaccess and don't understand a single word

Comment: Creating "virtual directories" as you call it, is done using Mod Rewrite, with Rewrite Rules. I'm sure if you spent more than 1 minute looking it up you'd find more information.

Comment: ok but how can i create .htaccess file ? just name it .htaccess ?

Comment: Yep, and stick it in the root folder of your website.

Comment: OK and how can i get the name of the user in htaccess file ?

Comment: Check out Mick Hansen's post below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume by virtual directories you mean rewrites. You have a profile.php page that loads the users profile via username or via id.

Lets take your first issue, mapping `/[username]` to `profile.php?username=[username]`.
This solution assumes that `mod_rewrite` is installed on your Apache server.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

(Place this in a .htaccess file in the root of your webapp or in the VirtualHost directory in your Apache conf)

This will internally rewrite any request to /[username] to profile.php?username=[username].

As for using a username when available, and a id when not - You will have to implemenent that when you generate the links.

```
<?php
$profile_url = $username ? : 'profile.php?id='.$userid;
?>
<a href="/<?php echo $profile_url; ?>">View profile</a>
```

That takes care of the link building. Then you have your profile.php page:

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$userid = $_GET['id'];

if ($username) {
    /* Load user via username */
} else {
    /* Load user via ID */
}
```

There are loads of tutorials on URL Rewriting with Apache on the internet, just google and make your way through some test setups.

Comment: ok I get the point, but this code redirects to profile.php and I want it instead.

Comment: I want that if user enters page profile.php?id=153511 than redirect to example.com/username this page

Comment: So, do that, check if username is set, if not, redirect to page with username

Answer (score 1):

It's url rewriting, look for it and you will find a lot of tutorials

Comment: None of them helped because I know absolutely nothing about .htaccess and don't understand a single word